# Edit all changes in git?

Tags: git, editor, diff

I have made a bunch of edits to my branch, in a number of files. I have now decided that I want to make some minor changes to almost all of those edits. Is there an easy way to get the filenames and line numbers of changes (eg. from `git diff`), and then open my editor of choice (vim, but assume any editor that can open a file at a specific line) at each of those positions in turn? The only way I can think off the top of my head is to run the diff output through some script, but that sounds like it could get pretty ugly..

Clarification: I haven't made any commits at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly you have several changes pending in your working copy.  You have not committed those changes anywhere and now you wish you'd done something slightly different in every one of those places.

What I would recommend is to use `git add -p` which will prompt you to `git add` each individual patch.  One of your options for each patch is `edit` which will drop you into an editor with the diff.  If you only need to modify a line you can just change the text on the added line (marked with `+`) and save.  It's slightly more complex to add or remove lines (though it does tell you how).

When you are done, `git diff --cached` will show you your new changes (as they will commit) while `git diff` will show that your working copy is still how it was when you started the `git add -p`.  You can then `git commit` the desired changes and then drop the unwanted ones with `git reset --hard` or assorted `git checkout` as usual.

Comment: That's pretty nice. For reference, [interactive adding](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_adding.html) (thanks carleeto for the original link)

Comment: Actually, that's a slightly different thing. Too hasty! I also notice that you can use the `git commit --interactive` as a shortcut to `git add -p; git commit -a`

Comment: @naught101: You can go straight to `git commit --interactive` but I prefer `git add -p` because you get multiple chances at it.  You can use `git reset <file>` to un-stage the patches from a file and try again.  You can review your work with `git diff --cached`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a manageable number of commits, you can interactively rebase them

```
git rebase -i lastcommitsha1^
```

and mark the ones you need to edit.

If there are a ton and the changes are scriptable, use `git filter-branch --tree-filter`

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is called an [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html):

```
git rebase -i <last_commit_you_want_to_keep>
```

The difference is that when you do the interactive rebase, you're going to choose to "edit" every single commit in the range. You're then going to continue the rebase and when prompted, you make the change to the commit that you want, commit it and continue the rebase. Keep going until you're done.

Word of caution: Before you start your rebase, create a temp branch, switch to it and perform the rebase on it. That way, if you mess up anything, you can always just switch back to the original code.

Comment: nice, but I don't think that will work, as I'm talking about code that I haven't commited yet.